# How can I use StartCoroutine to increment a variable value from 300 to 0 in 7 seconds increment by 1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The value of focalLength is start by 300.
I want to increment it by 1 until 0 in 7 seconds.
But my calculation is something wrong. The increment take much more time then 7 seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;

public class DOFControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcProf;

    public Animator anim;
    private float clipLength;

    private void Start()
    {
        AnimationClip[] clips = anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        StartCoroutine(incrementSpeed());
    }

    IEnumerator incrementSpeed()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var dof = postProcProf.depthOfField.settings;
            dof.focalLength -= 1f;
            if (dof.focalLength == 0)
                break;
            postProcProf.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.023f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for `WaitForSeconds`, especially what it says about scaled/unscaled time? Also that the wait time starts at the end of the current frame (which, assuming a 60 Hz refresh rate would mean a frame duration of 0.017 seconds, which in the worst case adds to your total waiting time; so your actual wait time per invocation would be in the range of [0.023... 0.04] seconds)

Comment: Dammit, i thought i did send this second comment of mine already, but i got distracted and forgot about it. Anyway, here it is with long delay: Since Coroutines in Unity are frame-based, you could do your decrement of the focal length parameter frame-based. As the whole thing is to be done in 1 second, all you need to do is to determine the refresh rate (=frames per second), and calculate the per-frame decrement step like `decrStep = 300f / refreshRate`, and use this value in the coroutine to decrease your focal length. WaitForSecond will not be necessary anymore with this approach.

Comment: You can't increment *from* 300 *to* 0. That's decrementing. Or overflow.

Answer (score 3):

To @elgonzo 's comment on your post, it might help you to understand how to use `WaitForSeconds`. Specifically (from the [API Documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)):
a) It varies with `Time.timeScale`. Do confirm that this is not your culprit.
b) From the same page,

> Note: There are some factors which can mean the actual amount of time waited does not precisely match the amount of time specified.

This is reasonable. The engine can only check if the duration you've set has passed. The code cannot not explicitly force the engine (and the governing operating system itself) to run code at an exact point of time.

This limits you to controlling only:
a) approximately how long (or with a slightly different approach, exactly how many frames) you want to wait before you run your code; and
b) how much your value changes per frame.

(I'm also slightly concerned about the `while (true)` statement there. I hope you understand its risks.)

Here's some quick pseudocode that might help you find what you're looking for:

```
private IEnumerator IncrementSpeed ()
{
    //_startValue = 300f;
    //_endValue = 0f;
    //_changeDuration = 7f;
    focalLength = _startValue;
    changeRate = (_endValue - _startValue) / _changeDuration;

    while (focalLength >= _endValue)
    {
        focalLength += changeRate * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!